# Foreign key that should be associated with multiple parent keys

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am facing the following database design issue.
I have three tables that stores asset info and one table that is used for retired assets.

**Vehicle**

```
ID. Primary key
Name.
Model.
Manufacture_year.
Manufacture _name.
Engine _size.
Price.
```

**IT**

```
ID. Primary key
Name.
Type.
Operating_system.
License_size.
price.
```

**Furniture**

```
ID. Primary key
Name.
Type.
Color.
price
```

**retired_asset**

```
    Asset_ID.  // I need to link this colum to the ID column for either the vehicle, IT or furniture table.
    Retired_reason.
    Date
```

So I have the following two questions:-

1. Since each asset have different columns and different business logic. So is my approach of storing each asset type on separate table a right approach?
2. In the `retired_asset` table, how can I link the foreign_key `asset_id` to the `ID` column in either the vehicle, IT or furniture tables?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You cannot do this. A foreign key **always** references **exactly one** (and only ever one) table. So you'd need a `vehicle_id`, `furniture_id` and `it_id` foreign keys in your `retired_asset` table, referencing the appropriate tables. Only one of those can ever be filled at any given time for any of the rows in `retired_asset`

Comment: INtroduce `Asset` table and subtype `Vehicle, Furniture, IT` to it. Link `RetiredAsset` to `Asset`. Example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A196713+subtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vehicle, IT, and Furniture are really subclasses of the class "Asset".

You might benefit by using a [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) approach combined with a shared primary key.  You can get the details by visiting the tag and clicking on info.

The big advantage you'll get by doing things this way is that the foreign key can always reference the Asset table, but will also reference one of the subclass tables by virtue of the magic of shared primary keys.

It's a bit of work to set up.  In your case, I recommend it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i though about having a general asset class. but the columns which i show is just a sample of all he columns . and most of the columns are not common . so that why i create completely separate tables for each asset type.

Comment: John, put the common columns in the asset class table and the ones that are specific to a subclass in a table for that subclass. The key is common to all the tables.